# Docker bind host to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers nginx and php how to configure docker-compose so when I make `wget http://example.com` from inside php container this host should point to nginx container

Answer (score 1):

Map your nginx port to host port.

If you host has name `example.com` and nginx runs on 8080 port, set up your docker-compose like

```
nginx:  
  image: nginx  
  hostname: nginx  
  ports:  
    - "8080:80"
```

In this case request to `http://example.com` will be really executed as `http://nginx:8080`.

Comment: maybe, I don't understand your solution, but this doesn't work for me. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've specified static ips for my containers in docker-compose.yml and added extra_host:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8200:80"
      - "8201:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "dev"
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
    extra_hosts:
      - "example.com:10.5.0.5"
networks:
  test:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

Comment: while this solution works, I changed it to more simple solution. In my case host machine has proxy for example.com to nginx container so I just changed "example.com:<host_id>" which looks better